# Cloth Passing Through cloth although interacting?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

so I wanted to simulate an object falling on a net and getting stopped by it. Basically everything is fine because both objects interact with each other but after some time the one object just falls through the net.
The net only has cloth physics.
The object has cloth and collision physics.
Any ideas?

I am going to include the blend file as well. There are some other things in there, just ignore them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: I am trying with Blend Exchange but it's not working i guess. It has uploaded completely but its not showing up.

Comment: just follow the instructions you see in the webpage....you have to copy and insert some lines to your question. it does work. believe me.

Comment: I did but it didn't show me the code to paste. I now uploaded it to drive. Here is the Link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1ShabdZx-3Vhs_TYdT7HONgoY8A42C5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please change the plane/wireframe in that way, that the scale is applied because this causes often problems

Comment: ok I applied the scale but that wasn't really the probelm. At least I didn't have any problems occuring because of that. The fish stil falls through. Also do u now a better way to make this kind of sim. Since the fish also has cloth physics it gets deformed quite a lot.